# Error parsing XML: not well-formed invalid token?

Tags: android, xml

I keep getting an error parsing XML: not well-formed error at android:layout_height="wrap_content". I saw from other answers that it could be a problem with opening and closing brackets, but these appeared ok to me. Why am I getting this error? Thanks!

activity_main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ball01" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton_background"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="Enlighten me!"
        android:textColor="#3f0f7f"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"       
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" <----- this is where I get the error
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is this happening at compile time or run time?  Can you post the error?

Comment: You might be missing this attribute 

android:orientation="vertical"

It is mandatory to provide orientation if there are more than one child.